# Task Scheduler requires account when enabling Run whether user is logged on or not

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

So basically when I try to make new task in my Task Scheduler in windows 10 home,
and then enabling `Run whether user is logged on or not` it requires an account,

Then I can see a list of some accounts, and I don't know what password should I use?

I tried to enter my PIN code but it didn't work

**Note:** I have exactly that problem: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/task-scheduler-asking-for-password/e2383480-74ac-4ca1-8fd3-572267daa3ea

but unfortunately it hasn't been answered.

Comment: "Then I can see a list of some accounts" - Which accounts?  can you be more specific?

Comment: @Ramhound edited my question with an example ( it has also a picture in it )

Comment: When prompted for the username and password, you provided the username and password, for a valid account on the machine?  `S-1-5-18` is the [Local System](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account) account which by default does not have a password.  You have to supply a password, the authentication prompt in question, does not support Windows Hello.

Comment: @Ramhound It pops up with that Username: "DESKTOP-ODMLDEM\MYUSER" tho I don't think it has a password, what could I do?

Comment: **In order to have a Windows Hello pin your account must have a password.**  If you don't know your password, then you will have to use an Administrator account, to reset the password.  If you are using EFS you need to recall what your password is, do not reset your password with another user's account, you will lose access to your files within the user's profile directory.  However, If you want specific help to your problem, then I need screenshots from your machine not a random user.  If your username is your name you can sanitize that information.

Comment: @Ramhound it worked, thanks! can you make a reply so I could make it as a solution?